# Android Circle Gradle Warning: The build VMs have a memory limit of 4G

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, circleci

Trying to run my Gradle Android project on circleci.com I got the following Warning:

**Warning: The build VMs have a memory limit of 4G. Your build hit this limit on one or more containers, and your build results are likely invalid.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using the [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) you can set `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` in `gradlew` like this:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
```

Set it in a similar fashion in `gradlew.bat` if you're on Windows:

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Xmx512m
```

those tell the JVM to limit the heap size. you can test different memory allocation for faster compilation time.

P.S it's actually made the compiling process locally on my machine to not chug my cpu. slower compiling but faster OS response.

Answer (score 12):

The GRADLE_OPTS can be set in the circle.yml file:

```
machine:
   environment:
     GRADLE_OPTS: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Allowing you to keep development configs and build configs separate.

**Edit:**

CircleCi have updated their [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/oom), this is the recommended config for Android builds:

```
machine:
  environment:
    GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
```

Comment: This is the right approach. I don't want circle concerns bleeding into my dev config.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need to set both gradle options and java options, as some libraries like NewRelic doesn't use jvm from gradle options variable and need java options variable

```
machine:
  environment:
    GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
    _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```